# IP Addresses of agents used when load testing

Tags: automated-testing, visualstudio

How can I find the IP addressses used by the agent computers in a Visual Studio load test? When using Microsoft's cloud based load testing service I see the status message that `This load test will run using 2 Internet Protocol (IP) addresses` but how do I learn what they are? I have not seen the addressses within the headers or bodies of the http(s) messages.

Whilst it would be possible to add a request to one of the many "what is my IP address?" servers I do not want to add that load to my tests nor to the external servers.

Comment: Does it need to be presented in the test results, or are you just looking for your own knowledge?

Comment: @LyndonVrooman Need to tell our customer the IP Addresses after the test run. In the results would be best. If I can get the value by program (eg in a plugin) then it should be easy to make it visible in the results. For example by inserting it into the "Reporting name" of a convenient request.

Comment: Hoping that someone else has come across this.  I'm unfortunately not completely certain how to do it automatically.  I've been looking for an excuse to use the cloud based tests to see how it differs from the on-prem service, but, I don't think that I'll get to it this week.

Comment: Are you using their cloud service or local agents?

Comment: @ECiurleo stated in the question *"... When using Microsoft's cloud based load testing service..."*.

Comment: Yes but you can configure the agent to use nodes within your network as well as their pool.

Comment: @ECiurleo Many things could be done. My customer does not have the time or budget for me to set up a pile of my own servers. I want to run a series of simple cloud based load tests using Microsoft's servers, which is exactly the usage pattern Microsoft provided when this service was first offered.

Comment: Ok... I was trying to clarify the question to give you a better answer. If you want to be defensive about that, then maybe this isn't the best forum for you

Comment: @ECiurleo Please take the time to read my original question.

Comment: @LyndonVrooman Thank you for your support on this question and for encouraging answers by offering the bonus. It is a shame that no one had an answer.

Comment: Any thoughts on using logging on the servers themselves that log specific messages corresponding to the test and list the IP and time stamp and any other pertinent information based on the traffic from the testing box to the other server?  Log messages would be pretty low performance and separate from the app itself, but just on the network traffic.  Not ideal, but it might work.

Comment: @mutt Nice idea, but how do you get the logging messages back from the cloud test computers? Microsoft only allocates them to me for the duration of the test run. After the test they are reallocated for other purposes.

Comment: well, you would have to change the logging to an external location.

Answer (score 1):

This answer doesn't directly get it with the load testing tools, but an alternate method.

Utilize logging to pull logs from each server and set the destination for the logging to an external location.  This will allow you to get the logs from each server respectively into a desired location for each server on your systems.  You will then be able to compare the server logs with the test execution to be sure know which server was doing what at what time.

*Note*: You will also need to be sure that the server and application logging is setup to sufficiently capture the traffic/activities you are after.

Comment: What logging do you suggest, how would it be created and where would it be written? Remember that this must all be done within Microsoft's cloud load testing facility.

Comment: I don't know all what Microsoft cloud allows to log, but it would be on their servers and likely you would not want all the debug stuff turned on as it would increase your load.  You don't mention the exact traffic you are after, but I would assume that a process is started on respective servers when the tests are run.  If you start an additional thread with each concurrent load user then you probably want to capture the thread counts as they increase on each machine.  Setup logging or get the cloud admins to setup logging so that each thread addition is logged as it starts/stops

Comment: The log path would go to a local directory that the network can access and a separate file for each server that would start by including the server IP it's coming from in the log.  How the IP is retrieved you would need to ask the cloud admins to help get that setup as they control all of that.

Comment: I think I follow your ideas. The problem is that the cloud load testing service does not provide the sort of logging you imply. It provides a service that uploads some files and data that form a load test. It then runs that test. Finally it downloads some results that are in a defined format. As far as I can see there are no facilities for adding extra data into the downloaded results. Hence my original question, how can I access and download some additional results - OK I only asked about IP addresses in this question but if I can download them then I can surely download other wanted data.

Comment: Do you have a sys admin support contact?  They have to have VMs or Physical boxes somewhere that you are connecting to.  Someone has to be managing them.  You would be discussing logging with them as they would have to configure that for you and you just provide what you need logged from each server.  Most places have something like that, they may add cost to it, or might reject altogether and say you can't.  In the latter case it's a dead end...but I'm hoping they will work with you some and allow logging remotely from the boxes you utilize during your tests.